# How to click on iCloud button in System Preferences using applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I am trying to get the script to click the iCloud button, but I am getting the syntax/logic incorrect.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts"
    delay 1
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "iCloud" of window "Internet Accounts"
    end tell
end tell
```

Help is much appreciated. I am on Monterey (12,4) iMac.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preferences.internetaccounts"
end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Preferences"
    repeat until exists of UI element "iCloud" of UI element 1 of row 1 of ¬
        table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Internet Accounts"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click button "iCloud" of UI element 1 of row 1 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of ¬
        group 1 of window "Internet Accounts"
end tell
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Is there any way to understand the UI elements and how to access them?

Comment: With "UI Scripting" you can use Automator's "Watch Me Do" to record the action of clicking on the "iCloud" button.  Then when you are done recording you can copy the recorded action from Automator and paste it into a Script Editor document and kind of reverse engineer it to have System Events perform the action.  https://pastebin.com/GRQXUGX9